# Cannot find module 'react-toastify' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, dependencies, pnpm

This is a part of a next js project. Package manager is pnpm. I have installed react-toastify dependency. It exists in my node-modules, and package.json but I am still getting the error of cannot find module.

I am facing the same issue with react-dropzone.

I am using type script so I tried doing `npm install @types/react-toastify --save-dev`  but that did not do anything.

Comment: Try restarting your TS server. If you don't know how to do it just close and reopen your editor just to see if that's fixes the issue.

Comment: Can you show us your tsconfig.json if problem still persists?